# How to animate a single element of an array in ngFor list in angular with angular/animations when the array reordered with sort?

Tags: angular, sorting, jquery-animate, ngfor

An array have to be reordered when an option modified, and the changed element of the array have to change its position (because of the sorting). It works simple and fine with ngFor without animation, but I have to animate it. When the sorting applies, the ngFor doesnt emit the the trigger to the animation, neither the array, neither the single element. Is there any way to solve this issue with angular ngFor sort and animate?

---

I added new properties to the elements (position and change), and solve the problem with a copy of the array in a new ng-container with ngIf, and some setTimeOut, but I think, this is not the right way.

Here is my solution on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngfor-sort-animate

This is my html:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="fake">
  <div
    *ngFor="let line of fakeArray"
    [@lineChanged]="line.change ? 'closed' : 'opened'"
    class="array-element">
    {{ line.value }}
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!fake">
  <div
    *ngFor="let line of myArray"
    [@lineChanged]="line.change ? 'closed' : 'opened'"
    (click)="toggle(line)"
    class="array-element">
    {{ line.value }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

This is my ts:

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {trigger,state,style,animate,transition} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('lineChanged', [
      state('closed', style({
        height: '0px',
        borderTop: '0',
        borderBottom: '0',
      })),
      state('opened', style({
        height: '*',
      })),
      transition('closed => opened', [
        animate(500)
      ]),
      transition('opened => closed', [
        animate(250)
      ]),
    ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  version = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  myArray = [
    {value: 'Value-1', position: 1, change: false },
    {value: 'Value-2', position: 2, change: false },
    {value: 'Value-3', position: 3, change: false },
    {value: 'Value-4', position: 4, change: false },
  ];
  fakeArray = [];
  fake = false;

  toggle(line: any) {
    line.position = -1;
    line.change = true;
    this.fakeArray = [];
    this.myArray.forEach(item => {
      this.fakeArray.push(item);
    });
    this.fakeArray.sort( (a, b) => a.position - b.position );
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fake = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.fakeArray[0].change = false;
        this.myArray.sort( (a, b) => a.position - b.position );
        let i = 1;
        this.myArray.forEach(item => {
          item.position = i++;
          item.change = false;
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.fake = false;
        }, 500);
      });
    }, 250);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array">` to iterate and then single out your element with `*ngIf`

Comment: I don't know how do you mean, and what will it couse. May you explain it a little bit more, please!